# I get an error that gs:// path can not be read by service account

Tags: google-cloud-ml

The GCS buckets I'm using for my ML jobs are encountering an access error. How do I make sure the service account has the required privileges?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by entering following:

$ gcloud beta ml init-project

Please see below for details.

https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to allow the service account to read/write to your bucket.

You will also need to change the default acl on your bucket so that new objects created in that bucket can be read by the service account.

You can do this using these two gsutil commands:

```
gsutil acl ch -u $SVCACCT:WRITE gs://$BUCKET/
gsutil defacl ch -u $SVCACCT:O gs://$BUCKET/
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

```
$ gcloud ml-engine init-project
```

This command will add Cloud ML Engine service accounts to your project as Editors. Operation requires OWNER permissions.