# Error when following google object detection API tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-cloud-ml-engine, google-cloud-sdk

While following the tutorial in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md#starting-training-and-evaluation-jobs-on-google-cloud-ml-engine), I've reached the stage of training the model on the cloud. Unfortunately, the command

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s` \
    --job-dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
    --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
    --module-name object_detection.train \
    --region us-central1 \
    --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
    -- \
    --train_dir=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/train \
    --pipeline_config_path=gs://${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/data/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
```

yields the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) FAILED_PRECONDITION:
>   Field: package_uris Error: The provided GCS paths
>   [gs://pet-detector-test/train/packages/[*REMOVED*]/slim-0.1.tar.gz,
>   gs://pet-detector-test/train/packages/[*REMOVED*]/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz] cannot be read by service account
>   service-[*REMOVED*]@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

*Note*: I have removed some specific identifiers from the error message and changed them to `[REMOVED]`

The bucket seems to contain all the necessary data, [image][image]

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780277/i-get-an-error-that-gs-path-can-not-be-read-by-service-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to skipping a step in [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up).
Specifically - use the following commands:

```
gcloud config set project [your-project-id]
gcloud auth application-default login
```